# How to show event date highlight(from database) in calender php

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I am using php in my project, for which I am using a JavaScript calendar. I have an event date in my database, which I want to highlight in my calendar. I have tried the following code:

**PHP**

```
$items = '';

        $selq = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ".$gettn." WHERE template_content_id = '$gettid'");

        $fetselq = mysql_fetch_array($selq);

        $linkId1 = $fetselq['id'];

        $getevent1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `template3event` WHERE tl3_id = '$linkId1'");
        //$items = array();
        while($fetcgetevent1 = mysql_fetch_array($getevent1)){
        $items .= date('d-F', strtotime($fetcgetevent1['date'])).',';
        }

        $event_date = substr($items, 0, -1);

        $event_dates = explode(',', $event_date);

        $Event_count = substr_count($event_date  , ',');

        // for($z = 0; $z <= $Event_count; $z++){
        //      echo $event_dates[$z].'<br>';
        // }
```

### JavaScript

```
// fill the month table with column headings
function day_title(day_name){
    document.write("<TD ALIGN=center WIDTH=35>"+day_name+"</TD>")
}
// fills the month table with numbers

function fill_table(month,month_length)
{

    day=1
    // begin the new month table
    document.write("<DIV CLASS='calender slide1'><P>"+month+"   "+year+"</P>")
    document.write("<TABLE width='240'><TR>")

    // column headings
    day_title("S")
    day_title("M")
    day_title("T")
    day_title("W")
    day_title("T")
    day_title("F")
    day_title("S")
    // pad cells before first day of month
    document.write("</TR><TR>")
    for (var i=1;i<start_day;i++){
        document.write("<TD>")
    }
    // fill the first week of days
    for (var i=start_day;i<8;i++){
        document.write("<TD><a href='#'>"+day+"</a></TD>")
        day++
    }
    document.write("<TR>")
    // fill the remaining weeks
    while (day <= month_length) {
        for (var i=1;i<=7 && day<=month_length;i++){
            var getcurrentmonth= $('#hiddenmonth').val();
            var getcurrentdate=$('#hiddendate').val();
            if(getcurrentmonth === month)
            {
                if(getcurrentdate == day )
                {

                    document.write("<TD><a style='color:rgb(65, 255, 0)' href='#'>"+day+"</a></TD>")
                }
                else
                {

                    document.write("<TD><a href='#'>"+day+"</a></TD>")
                }
            }
            else
            {
                document.write("<TD><a href='#'>"+day+"<a></TD>")
            }

            day++
        }
        document.write("</TR><TR>")
        // the first day of the next month
        start_day=i
    }
    document.write("</TR></TABLE></DIV>")
}
// end hiding -->

// CAHNGE the below variable to the CURRENT YEAR
var d = new Date();
var n = d.getFullYear();

var month = new Array();
month[0] = "January";
month[1] = "February";
month[2] = "March";
month[3] = "April";
month[4] = "May";
month[5] = "June";
month[6] = "July";
month[7] = "August";
month[8] = "September";
month[9] = "October";
month[10] = "November";
month[11] = "December";

var mm = month[d.getMonth()];

var dd=d.getDate();
today = mm+'/'+dd+'/'+n;

year=n

var leap = ((year % 4 == 0) && (year % 100 != 0)) || (year % 400 == 0);
var add = 0;
if(leap == true ){
    add = 1;
}
//alert(add);


$('#hiddenmonth').val(mm);
$('#hiddendate').val(dd);
// first day of the week of the new year
today= new Date("January 1, "+year)
start_day = today.getDay() + 1   // starts with 0
fill_table("January",31)
fill_table("February",28+add)
fill_table("March",31)
fill_table("April",30)
fill_table("May",31)
fill_table("June",30)
fill_table("July",31)
fill_table("August",31)
fill_table("September",30)
fill_table("October",31)
fill_table("November",30)
fill_table("December",31)
```

I have used a query to fetch data from the database. I don't know how to proceed to the next step. I only want to use this script to achieve this, I don't want to use jQuery.

Comment: Apply some class to that specific Date

Comment: Thanks for your reply. From database i can get multiple value(like 24-01-2015) i dont know how to pass those value through loop.

Comment: Are you using jQuery's Datepicker

Comment: No i am creating calender dynamically in javascript. you can see in above code. For example (24-01-2015) have to highlight this value in calender, like this date i ll get many values, have to show all in calender. I don't how to compare. Please gave some tips via jsfiddel.